# MPU6050 Settings?

Tags: mpu6050, gy-521

Does anybody have any good experience with the gy-521 / MPU6050 ?
I want to use the accelerometer portion to determine movement on a  swinging object.

I think i need some high precision settings, but for the life of me have not understood most of what i've found because they get to talking in "their" language, and i just get lost.

I know its probably just mathematical calculations, but i just don't seems to be getting the data from the module, at least the numbers don't seem to change as mush as i think they should when i move the module around.

I don't think i need decimal points of precision, just "high accuracy" as the module moves, whenever i request the data from it.

I suppose i could use decimal numbers, but like  i said i will just be reading on the fly and will track whatever number i get to see if its greater or less than the previous data read.

Sad part is right now if i just let the module sit still on my table top, about every 4-5 seconds, the numbers change without me doing anything to the module.
I'm pretty sure its a setup problem, because i'm just using the settings from the sample code i extracted from some example script i found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fundamentally not really a generic Tcl question, so I removed that tag.

Comment: No problem i just put that on there because at som epoint i thought someone would ask some details, in which wold be refernce to the tcl script i am using.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time last month just to understand MPU6050. From what I understand, you can change the settings correctly only if you understand the register map of MPU6050. After that, you can do the register setup. You may refer my repo (readme.md) for the setup and register details: https://github.com/aaryaapg/Digital-Level-Meter

I have also added references and links. You may check those out too.